# How to pass parameter to my hilt viewmodel from jetpack compose

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have a composable with viewmodel and I want to pass an id from the composable to the viewmodel.

My composable is:

```
@Composable
fun HttpRequestScreen(
    viewModel: HttpRequestViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    id: String = EMPTYUUID,
    onClick: (String, String, Int) -> Unit // respond, request Function: 1 - send request, 2 - edit request
) {
```

I have the id from a different screen and I want to pass it to my Hilt viewmodel.

Comment: What navigation library are you using? If you have that id from a different screen, your navigation library should pass it to the viewmodel inside SavedStateHandle or have some solution for this type of situation...

Comment: I'm using the default navigation (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

Comment: Do you have an example of the SavedStateHandle?

Comment: Yes, here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#retrieving-complex-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have followed the documentation for compose navigation, you can find your parameter here:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RouteDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getRouteByIdUC: GetRouteByIdUC,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {

    private val routeId = savedStateHandle.get<String>("your-param-name") // for example String in my case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to think in a Unidirectional Data Flow pattern, where events flow up and state flows down. For this, you need to expose some sort of state from your viewmodel that sends down the state of the request to the Composable as an observable state.

Your viewmodel could look like this.

```
class HttpRequestViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _httpResponse = mutableStateOf("")

    val httpResponse: State<String> = _httpResponse

    fun onHttpRequest(requestUrl: String) {
        // Execute your logic
        val result = "result of your execution"
        _httpResponse.value = result
    }
}
```

Then in your Composable, you can send events up by calling the ViewModel function on the button click like so

```
@Composable
fun HttpRequestScreen(viewModel: HttpRequestViewModel) {

    val state by viewModel.httpResponse

    var userInput = remember { TextFieldValue("") }

    Column {
        Text(text = "HTTP Response = $state")
    }

    BasicTextField(value = userInput, onValueChange = {
        userInput = it
    })

    Button(onClick = { viewModel.onHttpRequest(userInput.text) }) {
        Text(text = "Make Request")
    }
}
```

I hope that points you in the right direction. Good luck.